# problems with running tcsh file

Tags: compiling, tcsh, test

I can't get the following program to run. When I try running it, it says

```
set goal = `head -c 15 < /dev/urandom | base64 | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | sed'
Usage: tcsh [ -bcdefilmnqstvVxX ] [ argument ... ].
```

My code for the program is the following:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
echo "guess the number"
set answer = $<
set goal = `head -c 15 < /dev/urandom | base64 | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' | sed 's/\(.\).*/\1/'` 
set count = 1
while ($answer != $goal )
   if ($answer < $goal ) then echo "too small"
   else
      echo "too large"
   endif
   @ count ++
   set answer = $<
end
echo "correct!"
echo "using $count rounds"
```

Comment: You will want to put the `echo "too small"` on its own line, as it won't work with the `then` like this. Other than that, it works fine for me. I don't get the `Usage: tcsh ...` error. I don't quite understand the first code-block tough? That looks like half a line from the actual script? Was that intended?

Comment: Also, if at all possible, avoid scripting in `tcsh`. It has all sorts of quirks that will come back and bite you and it can be *very* difficult to debug if something goes wrong. Use some variant of a Bourne shell (`/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`) or a "real" programming language (such as Python, Ruby, Lua, whatever you prefer). It'll make your life a lot easier.